# JIRA JQL: How to search on issues closed before a time in the day?

Tags: jira, jql

I want to search for issues closed since 10am yesterday. startOfDay("-1d") only gets me from 8am... how do I tack on the last couple of hours?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Presumably you have configured your working day to start at 8am in the main JIRA configuration and likely configured JIRA to use a limited number of hours per working day as illustrated in section *Configuring Time Tracking Settings* within [Configuring Time Tracking](http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Configuring+Time+Tracking) as well. So depending on your actual configuration there might be two solutions:

- Either you need to use startOfDay("-6h"), assuming your *Hours per day* settings is 8 like in the illustration linked above.
- Or you need to use startOfDay("-22h"), assuming your *Hours per day* settings is 24.

Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

You can use startOfDay("-22h"). -2w (weeks), -2m(minutes) is valid as well.